# Need Multiple Values from Single Column

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssrs-2012

I am trying to join these two tables, or use a sub-query to achieve the results I need. 
As of now I have the first query pulling hourly totals with a overall total between MIN(time) and MAX(time). I need to join the second query to get the total scans from MIN(time) and MAX(time)
Any ideas of where I could be going wrong?

```
select 
UPPER(t.operator) as Operator,
CASE WHEN t.eventtype = 'Replenishment Complete' THEN (SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,t.time) = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) ELSE NULL END AS '6AM', 
CASE WHEN t.eventtype = 'Replenishment Complete' THEN (SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,t.time) = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) ELSE NULL END AS '7AM', 
CASE WHEN t.eventtype = 'Replenishment Complete' THEN (SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,t.time) = 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) ELSE NULL END AS '8AM', 
CASE WHEN t.eventtype = 'Replenishment Complete' THEN (SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,t.time) = 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) ELSE NULL END AS '9AM', 
CASE WHEN t.eventtype = 'Replenishment Complete' THEN (SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,t.time) = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) ELSE NULL END AS '10AM', 
CASE WHEN t.eventtype = 'Replenishment Complete' THEN (SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,t.time) = 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) ELSE NULL END AS '11AM', 
CASE WHEN t.eventtype = 'Replenishment Complete' THEN (SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,t.time) = 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) ELSE NULL END AS '12PM', 
CASE WHEN t.eventtype = 'Replenishment Complete' THEN (SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,t.time) = 13 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) ELSE NULL END AS '1PM', 
CASE WHEN t.eventtype = 'Replenishment Complete' THEN (SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,t.time) = 14 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) ELSE NULL END AS '2PM', 
CASE WHEN t.eventtype = 'Replenishment Complete' THEN (SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,t.time) = 15 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) ELSE NULL END AS '3PM', 
CASE WHEN t.eventtype = 'Replenishment Complete' THEN (SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,t.time) = 16 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) ELSE NULL END AS '4PM', 
CASE WHEN t.eventtype = 'Replenishment Complete' THEN (SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,t.time) = 17 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) ELSE NULL END AS '5PM',
CASE WHEN t.eventtype = 'Replenishment Complete' THEN (COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,t.time) > 17 THEN t.eventtype ELSE NULL END)) ELSE NULL END AS '6+PM',
SUM(CASE WHEN t.eventtype = 'Replenishment Complete' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as TotalCanisters

from mck_hvs.replevent t

where 
CAST(t.time  as DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() as DATE) 
and t.stationtype IN ('T', 'S')
and t.eventtype = 'Replenishment Complete'

group by 
t.operator,
t.eventtype
```

Second query:

```
select 
UPPER(o.operator) as Operator, 
SUM(CASE WHEN o.eventtype = 'GoodScan' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as TotalScans,
convert( varchar(19), MIN(o.time), 8) as LogonTime,
DATEDIFF(MINUTE, MIN(o.time), MAX(o.time)) as TotalMinLogon

from mck_hvs.replevent o

where 
CAST(o.time  as DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() as DATE) 
and o.eventtype IN ( 'Replenishment Complete', 'GoodScan' )

group by 
o.operator

order by o.operator
```

Comment: There is already `t.eventtype = 'Replenishment Complete'` in your `WHERE`. So I think you don't need this again in your `CASE` statemetns.

Comment: Well the problem is if I set t.eventtype IN ( 'Replenishment Complete' , 'GoodScan' ) it is not giving me the correct totals, and it is splitting the table  @KeyurPanchal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the below should get you headed to a solution.  I removed the group on t.eventtype and removed from the case statements because the where clause already limited the results for you.

```
select
    op.Operator,
    op.TotalScans,
    op.LogonTime,
    op.TotalMinLogon,
    b.[6AM],
    b.[7AM],
    b.[8AM],
    b.[9AM],
    b.[10AM],
    b.[11AM],
    b.[12PM],
    b.[1PM],
    b.[2PM],
    b.[3PM],
    b.[4PM],
    b.[5PM],
    b.[6+PM]
from 
(
    select 
        UPPER(o.operator) as Operator, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN o.eventtype = 'GoodScan' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as TotalScans,
        convert( varchar(19), MIN(o.time), 8) as LogonTime,
        DATEDIFF(MINUTE, MIN(o.time), MAX(o.time)) as TotalMinLogon
    from mck_hvs.replevent o

    where 
        --will use o.time index now:
        o.time >= CAST(GETDATE() as DATE) 
        and o.time < CAST(dateadd(Day,1,GETDATE()) as DATE)  
        and o.eventtype IN ( 'Replenishment Complete', 'GoodScan' )
    group by 
        o.operator
) as op
left join 
(
    select 
        UPPER(t.operator) as Operator,
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,t.time) = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '6AM', 
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,t.time) = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '7AM', 
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,t.time) = 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '8AM', 
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,t.time) = 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '9AM', 
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,t.time) = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '10AM', 
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,t.time) = 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '11AM', 
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,t.time) = 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '12PM', 
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,t.time) = 13 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '1PM', 
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,t.time) = 14 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '2PM', 
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,t.time) = 15 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '3PM', 
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,t.time) = 16 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '4PM', 
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,t.time) = 17 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '5PM', 
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,t.time) > 17 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '6+PM', 
        SUM(CASE WHEN t.eventtype = 'Replenishment Complete' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as TotalCanisters
    from mck_hvs.replevent t
    where 
        --will use o.time index now:
        o.time >= CAST(GETDATE() as DATE) 
        and o.time < CAST(dateadd(Day,1,GETDATE()) as DATE)  
        and t.stationtype IN ('T', 'S')
        and t.eventtype = 'Replenishment Complete'

    group by 
    t.operator 
) as b
on b.Operator = op.Operator
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  l.* ,
        r.TotalScans ,
        r.LogonTime ,
        r.TotalMinLogon
FROM    ( SELECT    UPPER(t.operator) AS Operator ,
                    CASE WHEN t.eventtype = 'Replenishment Complete'
                         THEN ( SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, t.time) = 6
                                         THEN 1
                                         ELSE 0
                                    END) )
                         ELSE NULL
                    END AS '6AM' ,
                    CASE WHEN t.eventtype = 'Replenishment Complete'
                         THEN ( SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, t.time) = 7
                                         THEN 1
                                         ELSE 0
                                    END) )
                         ELSE NULL
                    END AS '7AM' ,
                    CASE WHEN t.eventtype = 'Replenishment Complete'
                         THEN ( SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, t.time) = 8
                                         THEN 1
                                         ELSE 0
                                    END) )
                         ELSE NULL
                    END AS '8AM' ,
                    CASE WHEN t.eventtype = 'Replenishment Complete'
                         THEN ( SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, t.time) = 9
                                         THEN 1
                                         ELSE 0
                                    END) )
                         ELSE NULL
                    END AS '9AM' ,
                    CASE WHEN t.eventtype = 'Replenishment Complete'
                         THEN ( SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, t.time) = 10
                                         THEN 1
                                         ELSE 0
                                    END) )
                         ELSE NULL
                    END AS '10AM' ,
                    CASE WHEN t.eventtype = 'Replenishment Complete'
                         THEN ( SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, t.time) = 11
                                         THEN 1
                                         ELSE 0
                                    END) )
                         ELSE NULL
                    END AS '11AM' ,
                    CASE WHEN t.eventtype = 'Replenishment Complete'
                         THEN ( SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, t.time) = 12
                                         THEN 1
                                         ELSE 0
                                    END) )
                         ELSE NULL
                    END AS '12PM' ,
                    CASE WHEN t.eventtype = 'Replenishment Complete'
                         THEN ( SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, t.time) = 13
                                         THEN 1
                                         ELSE 0
                                    END) )
                         ELSE NULL
                    END AS '1PM' ,
                    CASE WHEN t.eventtype = 'Replenishment Complete'
                         THEN ( SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, t.time) = 14
                                         THEN 1
                                         ELSE 0
                                    END) )
                         ELSE NULL
                    END AS '2PM' ,
                    CASE WHEN t.eventtype = 'Replenishment Complete'
                         THEN ( SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, t.time) = 15
                                         THEN 1
                                         ELSE 0
                                    END) )
                         ELSE NULL
                    END AS '3PM' ,
                    CASE WHEN t.eventtype = 'Replenishment Complete'
                         THEN ( SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, t.time) = 16
                                         THEN 1
                                         ELSE 0
                                    END) )
                         ELSE NULL
                    END AS '4PM' ,
                    CASE WHEN t.eventtype = 'Replenishment Complete'
                         THEN ( SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, t.time) = 17
                                         THEN 1
                                         ELSE 0
                                    END) )
                         ELSE NULL
                    END AS '5PM' ,
                    CASE WHEN t.eventtype = 'Replenishment Complete'
                         THEN ( COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, t.time) > 17
                                           THEN t.eventtype
                                           ELSE NULL
                                      END) )
                         ELSE NULL
                    END AS '6+PM' ,
                    SUM(CASE WHEN t.eventtype = 'Replenishment Complete'
                             THEN 1
                             ELSE 0
                        END) AS TotalCanisters
          FROM      @replevent t
          WHERE     CAST(t.time AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
                    AND t.stationtype IN ( 'T', 'S' )
                    AND t.eventtype = 'Replenishment Complete'
          GROUP BY  t.operator ,
                    t.eventtype
        ) AS l
        INNER JOIN ( SELECT UPPER(o.operator) AS Operator_r ,
                            SUM(CASE WHEN o.eventtype = 'GoodScan' THEN 1
                                     ELSE 0
                                END) AS TotalScans ,
                            CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), MIN(o.time), 8) AS LogonTime ,
                            DATEDIFF(SECOND, MIN(o.time), MAX(o.time)) AS TotalMinLogon
                     FROM   @replevent o
                     WHERE  CAST(o.time AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
                            AND o.eventtype IN ( 'Replenishment Complete',
                                                 'GoodScan' )
                     GROUP BY o.operator
                   ) AS r ON l.Operator = r.Operator_r
ORDER BY l.Operator;
```